# action receive an empty string after ajax post

Tags: jquery, asp.net-mvc, json

I have a `js` function:

**Javascript:**

```
function Post()
{
    var table = $('#table4').dataTable();
    var data = table.$('input:text').serialize();
    console.log(data);

    $.ajax({
        type: "POST",
        url: '@Url.Action("SaveList")',
        data: JSON.stringify(data),
        dataType: "json",
        contentType: 'application/json',
        success: function () {
            alert('success');
        },
        error: function () {
            alert('error');
        }

    });
}
```

**Action:**

```
[HttpPost]
    public ActionResult SaveList(string serializedString)
    {
        var a = serializedString;
        return RedirectToAction("CustomersList");
    }
```

The problem is that action receive an empty sting `console.log(data)` shows, that there is content and if I put breakpoint on controller it stops but **serializedString** is empty. where could be a problem? Thanks!

Comment: Try `dataType:'text'` and remove `contentType`.

Comment: @FlorianGl — Saying `dataType: "text"` won't help. The problem is reading data on the server, not processing the response.

Comment: @FlorianGl — Removing the `contentType` would be stupid. The `data` contains JSON. If you remove the `contentType` then you'd need to reformat the data so it was form encoded data instead of JSON encoded data.

Comment: @user2710900 — Why are you form encoding the data (with `serialize()`) and then converting the resulting *string* to JSON?

Comment: Well, I don't know exactly why ...

Comment: What is the data you are actually POSTing to the server anyway? (Look in the Net tab of your browser's developer tools). Is it what you expect?

Comment: inputgrams=23423&id=3&inputgrams=243&id=1&inputgrams=423&id=4&inputgrams=234&id=5 yes that is what I need...I my contoller I would parse this string and make an list

Comment: All I want is to recieve string with id and inputgram parametrs

Comment: @Quentin My idea was, because of the contentType being `application/json`, `c#` tries to convert this json into an object an pass it to `SaveList`. Since it can't be converted into a `string`, it passes `null`. Through dataType `text` I thought `c#` maybe passes the data as a `string` to `SaveList`.

Comment: *Through default `contentType` I thought `c#` maybe passes the data as a `string` to `SaveList`.

Comment: @FlorianGl — If that is the problem then the solution is either to not send JSON or to fix the server side code to properly process the JSON. Not to lie about what is being sent.

Comment: @user2710900 — If you want to send form encoded data (which is what that syntax is) then why are you running everything through JSON.stringify (which will wrap it in quote marks) and saying you are sending JSON?

Comment: @Quentin Thats true, but all I wanted to achieve with my comment is the knowledge if my idea was right or wrong. If it was right, I would have written a detailed answer ;)

Answer (score 1):

Remove two statement from ajax function "       dataType: "json" and contentType: 'application/json', " try this

```
function Post()
{
    var table = $('#table4').dataTable();
    var data = table.$('input:text').serialize();
    console.log(data);

    $.ajax({
        type: "POST",
        url: '@Url.Action("SaveList")',
        data: JSON.stringify(data),

        success: function () {
            alert('success');
        },
        error: function () {
            alert('error');
        }

    });
}
```

Comment: I did not mean to vote down, I can't seem to change it... so sorry, I'll try again later

Answer (score 0):

Thank you guys, I solved a problem. Here is my code for now, maybe later I will change it.

**Javascript:**

```
function Post()
{
    var table = $('#table4').dataTable();
    var data = table.$('input:text').serialize();
    console.log(datas);
    $.ajax({
        type: "POST",
        url: '@Url.Action("SaveList")',
        data: data,
        datatype: 'json',
        success: function () {
            alert('success');
        }
    });
}
```

**Action:**

```
    public ActionResult SaveList(List<string> inputgrams, List<string> id)
    {
       ...
    }
```